# How to simplify "Percentage for each class"

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

I have the famous titanic data set

```
fr1 = pd.DataFrame({
"class": ["1", "2", "2"],
"survived": [0, 1, 1]})
```

I need to get the percentage of people who survived for each class, so first I separate applying a mask, then I group

```
fr2 = fr1[fr1["Survived"] == 0]
fr2 = fr2.groupby("Pclass", as_index=False)["Survived"].agg(["count"])
fr3 = fr1[fr1["Survived"] == 1]
fr3 = fr3.groupby("Pclass", as_index=False)["Survived"].agg(["count"])
```

Now I merged the data Frame I got and create the percentage column to know how many people survived for each class

```
merged = pd.merge(fr2,fr3,left_index=True,right_index=True)
merged.columns = "Survived Died".split()    
merged["Percentage"] = merged["Survived"] / (len(fr1))*100
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple method, as you already have 0/1, just get the [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html):

```
out = (fr1.groupby('class')['survived']
          .mean().mul(100).reset_index()
       )
```

Variant:

```
out = (fr1.groupby('class', as_index=False)['survived']
          .agg(lambda g: g.mean()*100)
       )
```

Output:

```
  class  survived
0     1       0.0
1     2     100.0
```